# Rotation for rolling 3d ball

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, rotation

I have a Ball in 3D space that has the following attributes:

location - a Vector3f representing where the ball is
rotation - a Vector3f representing the x, y, and z axis rotation angles

I want to roll the ball in a particular direction denoted by a Vector3f "direction". How would I calculate the appropriate axis rotation vector (see above) based on the direction I want the ball to roll towards?

I've tried the following:

1. set rotation.x to direction.z
2. set rotation.z to direction.x

Calculate the ball's transform matrix as:

```
private Matrix4f calculateEntityMatrix(EEntity entity)
{
    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
    matrix.translate(new Vector3f(entity.getXLocation(), entity.getYLocation(), entity.getZLocation()));

    if(entity.getXRotation()>0)
    {
        matrix = matrix.rotate(entity.getXRotation(), new Vector3f(1f, 0f, 0f));
    }
    if(entity.getYRotation()>0)
    {
        matrix = matrix.rotate(entity.getYRotation(), new Vector3f(0f, 1f, 0f));
    }
    if(entity.getZRotation()>0)
    {
        matrix = matrix.rotate(entity.getZRotation(), new Vector3f(0f, 0f, 1f));
    }
    if(entity.getXScale()!=1 || entity.getYScale()!=1 || entity.getZScale()!=1)
    {
        matrix = matrix.scale(new Vector3f(entity.getXScale(), entity.getYScale(), entity.getZScale()));
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

This works when rolling down either the x or z axis, but when I roll in a direction between the two axes the rotation appears incorrect. My assumption is that this is caused by the fact that the rotation is being calculated as follows:

1. the ball is rotated by rotation.x along the X axis
2. the ball is then rotation by rotation.z along "new" X axis created by step 1.

Any suggestions how this behaviour could be changed so that each rotation is calculated independently of each other?

Comment: Make sure to prevent [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) from happening. Or use quaternions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to implement slipping and/or backspin, I think you should approach this problem slightly different. You already have a `Matrix.rotate()` that supports rotation around an arbitrary axis, *use it*.

**Attributes to store for the ball**

- position
- rotation matrix

*Note: in a matrix-oriented system / scene graph, bould would usually be stored in a single 4x4 transformation matrix. That might or might not be more convenience, depending on the rest of your current code base.*

**Algorithm for moving around**

1. Given the ball `direction` and the standard up vector `(0, 1, 0)`, calculate the `rotation axis` using the cross product. (i.e. it's perpendiciular to both direction and up axis)
2. Rotation is now simply a `matrix.rotate( rotationSpeed, rotationAxis)`, applied to the existing rotation matrix.

If the ball is allowed to roll up/down surfaces, replace the standard up vector with the appropriate surface normal.